# Why does MATLAB 'forget' updates to variables inside objects?

Tags: matlab

If I have a MATLAB class MyClass with a

```
classdef MyClass 

    properties
        myArray
    end

    methods

        function update(obj, i)
            obj.myArray[i] = i*5;
        end
end
```

and I call the update function with

```
myClass.update(i)
```

the myArray object does not 'remember' the updates when i increments and I get left with an empty property. Ie. myArray = []

However if I define the function as follows

```
classdef MyClass 

    properties
        myArray
    end

    methods

        function out = update(obj, i)
            out = i*5;
        end
end
```

and call the update function with

```
myClass.myArray[i] = update(i)
```

the updates to the myArray property are remembered. Ie. Ie. myArray = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25]

So what is going on here?...in every other language this would work as expected, it seems like there is some MATLAB specific weird scoping/referencing going on here. Anybody know what's happening?

Comment: There are syntax errors in the code you pasted here.

Answer (score 4):

```
classdef MyClass
```

This defines a *value class*. Think of value classes as immutable: a member function of a value class should return a new instance of the value class.

You want a *handle class*, which is declared using the syntax

```
classsdef MyClass < handle
```

See [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/comparing-handle-and-value-classes.html) for more info.